# VB.Net Handling Multiple Forms into Panel

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have tried to find an answer to this already, but cannot find one that answers this question.

I have a Master Form which contains two panels. In the master Form I am trying to write a subroutine to handle the loading of a form into one of the panels.

One panel always contains the same form and the code which works for this is:

```
'Configure Toolbar Import
Dim toolbarHandler As _pnl_header = New _pnl_header()
toolbarHandler.Size = pnlHeader.Size
toolbarHandler.TopLevel = False
pnlHeader.Controls.Add(toolbarHandler)
toolbarHandler.Show()
```

The panel successfully shows the form _pnl_header as expected.

The second panel will change the displayed form depending on user input, so rather than having to write the above code for every eventuality i would like one Public Sub to handle them all...

I've started writing a sub along the lines of:

```
Public Sub LoadContentPanel(WhichForm As Form)
    Try

        Dim contentHandler As WhichForm = New WhichForm()
        contentHandler.Size = pnlContent.Size
        contentHandler.TopLevel = False
        pnlContent.Controls.Add(contentHandler)
        contentHandler.Show()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Unable to Handle Content Panel Change. Error: " & ex.Message, vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Load Error")
    End Try
End Sub
```

However this fails as 'WhichForm' is not defined - how is best to correct this? or is there a better alternative?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't sound like you created a Form Class called WhichForm.  What "form" are you trying to put into the panel?

Comment: I have a number of forms that are able to go into the panel for example forms called

Comment: I have a number of forms that are able to go into the panel for example forms called FORM1, FORM2, FORM3 for example and want to pass them to the sub by doing:      LoadContentPanel(FORM1) ... but it doesnt like that.

Comment: What are you passing when you call `LoadContentPanel`?

Comment: The name of an existing Form in the Project, i.e. FORM1

Comment: Then get rid of your `contentHandler` variable, replace it with the `WhichForm` variable.  Remove the `new WhichForm()` line, too, since that's meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Without going into what you are doing I can explain where the error comes from.

Here you declare argument variable `WhichForm` of type `Form`

```
Public Sub LoadContentPanel(WhichForm As Form)
. . . . .
```

Code is incorrect in the next declaration line. `WhichForm` is a variable and not a type. Hence

```
Dim contentHandler As WhichForm = New WhichForm()
```

is invalid at `As WhichForm`. Because after `As` you need a type name. If you did

```
Dim contentHandler As Form = New Form()
```

it would work.

It seems that all you need to do is remove `Dim contentHandler As WhichForm...` and rename argument `WhichForm` to `contentHandler`.